# Forcing GCC to compile .cpp file as C

Tags: c++, c, gcc, compilation

I have an externally provided .cpp file. It is a mixture of C compatible code and a bit of C++ as well. The C++ code is just a wrapper around the C to take advantage of C++ features.

It uses `#ifdef __cplusplus` macros to protect the C++ code, which is great. Unfortunately, if I try to compile using GCC, it treats it as C++ because of the file ending. I'm aware of the differences between `gcc` and `g++` - I don't want to compile as C++.

Is there any way I can force GCC to treat this file as a C file? I've tried using e.g. `--std=c99`, but this correctly produces the error that C99 isn't valid for C++.

Renaming the file to .c works, but I'd like to avoid this if possible because it's externally provided and it'd be nice for it to remain as a pristine copy.

Comment: Sometimes when I see SO questions. I just want to scream a big RTFM!! `man gcc`. For this king of question it actually takes less time than writing the question.

Comment: I had the same problem because I wanted to compile pure C code within a .cpp file...obviously I'm quite a beginner concerning C. RTFM! is not such a good advice then. gcc man pages are 11.000 lines and it's kind of hard to find a solution in there if you don't know what to look for.

Comment: I disagree, reading documentation is never a loss of time, and the documentation of GCC is IMHO well written

Answer (score 76, accepted):

The `-x` option for `gcc` lets you specify the language of all input files following it:

```
$ gcc -x c your-file-name.cpp
```

If you only want to special-case that one file, you can use `-x none` to shut off the special treatment:

```
$ gcc -x c your-filename.cpp -x none other-file-name.cpp
```

(`your-filename.cpp` will be compiled as C, while `other-file-name.cpp` will use the extension  and compile as C++)

Comment: How embarrassing, I must have paged right past it! Thanks very much, the same to everybody else who answered.

Answer (score 17):

To compile *foo.cpp* as a C file, you can create a new file named *foo.c* and put the following as its entire contents:

```
#include "foo.cpp"
```

Now compile *foo.c* instead of *foo.cpp*.

We've used this to go the other way (compile a *.c* file as C++) in order to start using C++ features in some files while preserving their decade-long CVS history. Also, we build using each platform's native compiler, not just GCC, so we didn't have to find the `-x` equivalent command for a half-dozen compilers, and then make our build system apply that command only to certain files.

Comment: Works as charm and quickest mentioned solution possible I think.