# Avoid name mangling on a shared object C interface under linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, shared-objects, name-mangling

Under windows we have a C interface (extern "C" { // interface }) to our C++ library, that exports unmangled functions using a module definition file (.def).

I am trying to recreate the same thing under linux, where I am relatively inexperienced. I understand that under NIX systems, all functions are exported by default. With this in mind I created a shared object, which I ran through the nm command.

I was surprised to see that, unlike in windows, my function names had been mangled!

How can I prevent this please?

Comment: @pmg - Apologies, I have amended the question.

Comment: Are you sure you don't just want to compile a shared library and then link your main program to it? The basic functionality of what you do through .def files in windows is done automatically here.

Comment: gcc -x c maybe? From answer on [Here][1] :)


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216247/forcing-gcc-to-compile-cpp-file-as-c

Comment: your question makes no sense to me. If you declare, say, a function `myfunc(double)` as `extern "C"` *and* the code implementing that function has seen that definition, then it will *not* be name-mangled in the object file.

Comment: I think we need a small but complete example of your `extern "C" { //interface }`. You shouldn't be having this problem.

Answer (score 9):

The usual solution is to declare the functions `extern "C"`.  This not only causes the names to be  mangled as in C, but also for the function to use the C calling conventions.

Comment: @James - Thanks for the reply, we are using extern "C", that's what i meant by a "C interface". I have updated the question to make this clearer.

Comment: @ScarletAmaranth That depends on the C compiler.  Historically, most C compilers did mangle external names, but in a very, very simple way (prefixing a `_` was the most common).

Comment: @dangerousdave If the function is declared `extern "C"`, the name should appear exactly as if it were a C function.  With g++ under Linux, this means no mangling; with most Unix compilers, this means just a `_` prefixed to the name.

Comment: @R I'm not sure what's confusing and misleading about it.  The requirements of the standard are that the function appear exactly as if it were written in C.  This means that the same mangling must be used as in C (and most C compilers I've used _do_ mangle).

Comment: @JamesKanze o_O ? C actually used to mangle external names ? Well that's news to me, I apologize for the comment then! :)