# Building foo.cpp as C code with Microchip XC16 compiler

Tags: c++, c, xc16

I have some code that is shared between a C++ Windows application and an XC16 C application. The source is written in such a way that it compiles cleanly under MSVC and XC16 (with appropriate use of the `__cplusplus` macro).

The problem is that XC16 refuses to build `foo.cpp`. I have to copy the file to `foo.c` and back again. This is wreaking havoc on revision control, and making code edits within the ide problematic when the copying functions are automated in the build process.

Is there a way to get XC16 to build (as C) a file with the extension cpp? (note that the header file is `foo.h`, so it is not an issue).

Comment: Why don’t you compile it as C on MSVC?

Comment: How are you building for Windows? VisualStudio?, MSBuild?

Comment: In the Windows environment, the code is encapsulated in a class (so it needs to be built with C++). This is not possible when compiled as C with a 16-bit microprocessor target.

Comment: Don't know about XC16, but MSVC has options to build as C or C++ with any extension. [Specify Source File Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/032xwy55.aspx)

Comment: @BoPersson Thanks. We found a similar solution (see my answer). Unfortunately this does not seem to be an option for XC16. More specifically, I think the problem lies with MPLABX, which dynamically builds the makefile.

Comment: You should compile C code as C in both cases; in the C++ app you could have a wrapper that wraps the C code without requiring modification of the C code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We discovered a flag in one of our Windows build environments (Embarcadero CBuilder) that forces compiling `foo.c` as C++. We'll therefore rename to `foo.c`. Problem solved. (EDIT: Others have commented that similar flags exist in VC)

We could not find a comparable flag in XC16 (based on gcc 4.5.1) to treat `foo.cpp` as a C source file. The -x flag ([Forcing gcc to compile .cpp file as C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216247/forcing-gcc-to-compile-cpp-file-as-c)) does not seem to work under MPLABX.