An empty program that does nothing in C++ needs a heap of 204KB but not in C
Consider this empty program:
int main()
{ return 0; }

If I compile it with C++ with g++ main.cpp && strace ./a.out, and analyze the output with strace, I observed that the last lines of the output are (you can add -O3 that the effect is the same):
mprotect(0x7f71af154000, 45056, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f71af38b000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0xed2000
brk(0xf05000)                           = 0xf05000
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++

However, if I do instead: gcc main.cpp && strace ./a.out
mprotect(0x7f4114318000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f4114547000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++

As you see, in C++ there's an extra brk that extends the heap by exactly 204KB (0xf05000 - 0xed2000 = 204KB after translating both to decimal). That can be easily verified by replacing that program by (coliru link):
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    char buf[1024];
    sprintf(buf, "pmap -XX %u", getpid());
    std::system(buf);
    
    return 0;
}

and you can easily observe that compiling with g++ the [heap] has a size of 204KB, and with gcc the [heap] line even disappeared from the pmap output.
NOTE: By the way, and to my surprise, gcc had no problem at all with include <iostream> and with the presence of std in std::system.
What are these 204KB used for? Not worried or anything about these little 204KB but it caught my attention and I'm curious now.

The C++ crt might do a lot of things in the background before actually calling main. Your best bet is to check the source code of the generator, if you really want to know what happens in the background.

@MichaelChourdakis gcc has a crt?

Does this happen if you compile with optimization enabled?

@Barmar Yes, even with -O3.

No, it doesn't. At least the assembly isn't.

@sweenish Godbolt doesn't show what happens before main, at least not by default.

Both gcc and g++ will determine the language based on file extension, regardless which one you will use, so gcc is able to compile C++ just fine. Use -x flag to override that. The main difference is that g++ will link C++ standard library into the final executable by default and gcc will not. So if you used something that is not header-only (presumably std::system is just ::system brought into namespace std) you would run into linker errors.

C++ startup has plenty of things to do and allocate space for. Try disabling RTTI and exceptions (-fno-rtti -fno-exceptions) and see if it changes anything

Okay, learning is a journey and all that. Running it in my WSL, I see what you're seeing too.

cin and cout are objects, and they contain state.  There is also other things in the standard that need to be available before everything else in the global scope.  most likely this space is related to that.

@NathanOliver I rather suspect exceptions or RTTI

Remove the libraries added by g++ and it will not do the extra allocation: g++ -nodefaultlibs -lc main.cpp && strace ./a.out

@TedLyngmo Yes, adding -nodefaultlibs -lc removed that. -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions had no effect. I wonder anyway which specific C++ lib increased the heap.

@NathanOliver I understand that if you don't include <iostream>, the global objects cin and cout are not visible/available. That library is the one that import those objects right?

In theory #include <iostream> needs to be in the code but other includes could also bring it in.  The compiler could also just decide to bring it in anyways.  Other things like new, exception handling, RTTI also need to be available at the start of the global space.

For compiling a file with extention .cpp as pure C code, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216247/forcing-gcc-to-compile-cpp-file-as-c

One major difference between C and C++ is that C++ may shamelessly use heap allocation inside standard libs, whereas the C standard libs never do that unless explicitly mentioned (strdup etc). So I don't get what the fuss is about. You picked C++, so here's the heap allocation that you ordered by choice of language.

@Lundin As I said in the question, I'm just curious to know WHY, to learn a bit more. I haven't stated in any place that I have any problem with that at all.

This is due to the emergency buffer allocated by the C++ language runtime. When an exception is thrown, the runtime makes a copy of the thrown object in dynamically allocated memory. If it is unable to dynamically allocate enough memory, the GCC implementation falls back to allocating space from an emergency buffer it allocates at program startup. If that fails, it calls std::terminate().
This behaviour is implementation-defined. You will find other C++ language runtime implementations may do things differently.

Is the emergency buffer worth 200KiB? I have been inspecting a bit the code, with that formula of EMERGENCY_OBJ_COUNT * (EMERGENCY_OBJ_SIZE * sizeof(void*) + sizeof(__cxa_refcounted_exception) + sizeof(__cxa_dependent_exception)), and I have been doing my math, and unless these two __cxa types are very large, getting close to 200KB is hard. The only way is by both sizeof(__cxa_x) to add together more than 700B, or around 90 pointers of overhead. Are exceptions really that expensive?

This then begs the question of whether -fno-exceptions will give us back the 204KB. My limited testing indicates it doesn't.

-fno-exceptions does not stop the C++ language runtime from being linked in, so no it's not going to make any difference.

@ABu On my Fedora 40 system, the emergency pool becomes exacly 73728 bytes, so that pool object is just one of those extra objects that libstdc++ creates that I mentioned in my answer and it does not account for the full 204 KiB. There are 135168 bytes unaccounted for :-)

Remove the libraries added by g++ and it will not do the extra allocation:
g++ -nodefaultlibs -lc main.cpp

With the default libraries, the C++ program gets linked to:
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6
libstdc++.so.6 => /lib64/libstdc++.so.6
linux-vdso.so.1

Without the default libraries + libc:
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6
linux-vdso.so.1

The extra libraries being:
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6
libstdc++.so.6 => /lib64/libstdc++.so.6


I wonder anyway which specific C++ lib increased the heap

By adding the extra libraries to the linking one at a time, we can see that it's libstdc++ that causes the extra allocation, so if you can get away without the compiled part of the C++ standard library, this is what you could use:
g++ -nodefaultlibs -lgcc_s -lm -lc


Single-stepping through the program compiled with the default libraries shows the construction and destruction of misc. standard C++ objects, such as this std::atomic<std::shared_ptr<std::chrono::tzdb_list::_Node>>. The timezone database alone ought to take up a bit of space, but I'm not sure if that alone covers the full 204 KiB you observed. The conclusion is however that the C++ standard library has more objects (in addition to those in the C standard library) that are implicitly constructed (the standard iostreams for example):
$ gdb -tui ./a.out
(gdb) layout asm
(gdb) start
(fiddling about for a long time)
(gdb) tui d
(gdb) bt
#0  std::atomic<std::shared_ptr<std::chrono::tzdb_list::_Node> >::~atomic (this=0x7ffff7e62810 <std::chrono::tzdb_list::_Node::_S_head_owner>, __in_chrg=<optimized out>)
    at /usr/src/debug/gcc-14.2.1-3.fc40.x86_64/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/x86_64-redhat-linux/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/shared_ptr_atomic.h:630
#1  0x00007ffff7a51e60 in __cxa_finalize (d=0x7ffff7e52200) at cxa_finalize.c:82
#2  0x00007ffff7cb4947 in __do_global_dtors_aux () from /lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#3  0x00007fffffffd750 in ?? ()
#4  0x00007ffff7fc90f2 in _dl_call_fini (closure_map=0x7ffff7f8a000) at dl-call_fini.c:43


Any idea what clang's libc++ "costs"?

@Botje oh... nope - and it's too late for me to start digging there too right now :-)

@Botje With clang++ you see the exact same 204KB of heap.

@ABu You need to use clang++ -stdlib=libc++ to make it link with LLVM's implementation of the C++ standard library (it will use the gcc version, libstd++, by default on most platforms). With -stdlib=libc++ it doesn't show the same brks for me but I am in bed and can't investigate it properly from here :-)

Ok linking explicitly with -stdlib=libc++ the heap is now 200KB. We are a page wealthier now.

The C++ standard library allocates some amount of memory from the heap in its global constructors and initialization. However, it likely does not allocate 204 kB total. Instead the standard memory allocator requests memory from the operating system in larger chunks, to avoid system call overhead.
If you allocate 1 byte from heap with malloc(), you'll see a similarly sized allocation also compiled as a C program:
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  void *dummy = malloc(1);
  return 0;
}

For C, the allocation size can be adjusted with a glibc tunable.
Easiest way to set this is to modify the MALLOC_TOP_PAD_ environment variable. The smallest allocable block is 4 kB.
I'm not sure if there is a similar runtime tunable for the libstdc++ allocator.

What I have observed is that the initial allocation is by a direct call to brk by libstdc++ without a call to malloc. In other words, libstdc++ is calculating and applying the new brk directly. So malloc looks like is not involved at all.

@ABu Ok, then the behavior is slightly different from what I'm seeing on my system. I wonder if GLIBCXX_TUNABLES=glibcxx.eh_pool.obj_count=0 might change it. You may want to specify your glibc and libstdc++ versions in the question.
